# Bind generated input field to variable for validation

Tags: angular

My app generates forms from an array of inputs and has an error for each input that pops up when the field is invalid. The interfaces are defined as below:

```
export interface InputError {
    id: string;
    desc: string;
    field: string;
}

export interface Field {
    name: string;
    label: string;
    type: string;
    placeholder: string;
}
```

And I'm using these test values

```
errors: InputError[] = [{id: "test", desc: "Test error!", field: "test"}];
fields: Field[] = [{name:"test", label: "Test", type:"text", placeholder:"test field"}];
```

The form is displayed by using ngFor and ngSwitch (to allow other elements to be placed in the forms such as images). For example the input is presented as:

```
<input class="form-control" autocomplete="off" required ngModel 
    [name]="f.name" 
    [type]="f.type" 
    [id]="f.name" 
    [placeholder]="f.placeholder"
>
```

While this all works fine and dandy, I want to toggle the errors on for these generated fields. Errors are displayed as so:

```
<div class="error" *ngIf="???.invalid && (???.touched || ???.dirty)">
    {{e.desc}}
</div>
```

I've put "???" where the variable bound by ngModel should go, not sure how to set and get this variable name.

Comment: i suggest to push data in the array